# Firing onKeyUp event registered with parent when child's onClick is fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, keyboard-events

I have a function named `onKeyUp` defined as follows which listens for escape and enter key

```
const onKeyUp = (targetKey: string, event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const key = event.keyCode;
    const editString = event.currentTarget.textContent;
    switch (key) {
        case 27: // escape key
        case 13: // enter key
            if (editString.trim().length === 0) {
                MOpenSnackBar({
                    message: {
                        key: new Date().getTime(),
                        message: "Target segment cannot be empty"
                    },
                    open: true
                });
            } else {
                if (editString.trim() !== currentVal.trim()) {
                    props.onChangeCallback(targetKey, editString);
                }
                removeEditMode(targetKey);
            }
            break;
    }
};


const done = (targetKey: string, event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement, MouseEvent>) {
   // call onKeyUp here
}
```

It is defined on the div which looks like:

```
<div onKeyUp={onKeyUp.bind(null, props.targetStringId)}>

       .. some tags here
       <Tag onClick={done.bind(null, props.targetStringId)}>Done</Tag>
       .. some more tags here
</div>
```

I want to fire the same event `onKeyUp` when someone clicks the `Tag` as is fired `onKeyUp` for the `div`.

How could I do this?

Comment: event.stopPropagation() may help you :D

Comment: @AnhTuan Didn't get you

Comment: @AnhTuan OMG!!!!! You got it. It will be great if you could add this an answer!!

Comment: you are welcome ^^ i get this problem before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add  `event.stopPropagation()` in to your `onKeyUp()` function :D